# Does GAE Datastore support eager fetching?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, eager-loading, database-optimization

Let's say I want to display a list of books and their authors.  In traditional database design, I would issue a single query to retrieve rows from the `Book` table as well as the related `Author` table, a step known as *eager fetching*.  This is done to avoid the dreaded *N+1 select problem*: If the `Author` records were retrieved lazily, my program would have to issue a separate query for each author, possibly as many queries as there are books in the list.

Does Google App Engine Datastore provide a similar mechanism, or is the N+1 select problem something that is no longer relevant on this platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are implicitly asking if Google App Engine supports JOIN to avoid the *N+1 select problem*.
Google App Engine does not support JOIN directly but lets you define a `one to many relationship` using [ReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#References).

```
class Author(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Book(db.Model):
  title = db.StringProperty()
  author= db.ReferenceProperty(Author)
```

In you specific scenario, with two query calls, the first one to get the author:

```
author = Author.all.filter('name =' , 'fooauthor').get()
```

and the second one to find all the books of a given author:

```
books = Book.all().filter('author=', author).fetch(...)
```

you can get the same result of a common SQL Query that uses JOIN.

The *N+1* problem could for example appear when we want to get 100 books, each with its author name:

```
books = Book.all().fetch(100)
for book in books:
    print book.author.name
```

In this case, we need to execute 1+100 queries, one to get the books list and 100 to dereference all the authors objects to get the author's name (this step is implicitly done on `book.author.name` statement).

One common technique to workaround this problem is by using `get_value_for_datastore` method that retrieves the referenced author's key of a given book without dereferencing it (ie, a datastore fetch):

```
author_key = Book.author.get_value_for_datastore(book)
```

There's a brilliant [blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine) on this topic that you might want to read.
This method, starting from  the `author_key` list, prefetches the authors objects from datastore setting each one to the proper entity book.
Using this approach saves a lot of calls to datastore and practically <sup>*</sup> avoids the *N+1* problem.

<sup>* theoretically, on a bookshelf with 100 books written by 100 different authors, we still have to call the datastore 100+1 times</sup>

Answering your question:

- Google App Engine does not support
  *eager fetching*
- There are techniques (not out of the box) that
  helps to avoid the dreaded *N+1
  problem*

Comment: @Jen have a look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships)